# Zend How to repopulate a form after a redirection?

Tags: forms, zend-framework

i'm looking for a solution to re-populate a form after a redirection.

I'm using Zend flash message to toggle actions errors, and to display it i use redirect method.

```
$this->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Sauvegarde réalisée !');
$this->redirect('/control/action');
```

Comment: Please post your redirection code, and your `Zend_Flash_Message` use code.

Answer (score 1):

Set POST data in session, retrieve it after redirection and unset it from session.

E.g.

```
$userSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user_session');
$userSession->formPostData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$this->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Sauvegarde réalisée !');
$this->redirect('/control/action');
```

In your action after redirection, use below code:

```
$userSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user_session');
$formData = $userSession->formPostData;
$formObject = new yourZendForm();
$formObject->populate($formData);
unset($userSession->formPostData);
```

Other alternative solutions is, instead of redirecting to another action use `_forward` with posting data in the request.

E.g.

```
$this->getHelper('FlashMessenger')->addMessage('Sauvegarde réalisée !');
$formData = $userSession->formPostData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$this->_request->setPost(array('formData' => $formData));
$this->_forward('action', 'controller', 'module');
```

And after forwarding control to another action retrieve data using `getPost` as shown below:

```
 if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $previousFormData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $formObject = new yourZendForm();
    $formObject->populate($previousFormData);
}
```